# Bootstrap drop down list doesn't working

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I am using bootsrap for my web site and in the master page, the drop down list does work on default.aspx but doesn't open on other pages.

```
                      <li class="dropdown">
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false"><%Response.Write(Session["isim"].ToString() + " " + Session["soyisim"].ToString());%> <span class="caret"></span></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li ><a style="color:black" href="#">İlanlarım</a></li>
            <li><a style="color:black" href="#">Bakiye: <asp:Label ID="lblBakiye" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>₺</a></li>
            <li ><a style="color:black" href="../kisi/ayarlar.aspx?uyeID=<%Response.Write(uyeid.ToString());%>">Ayarlar</a></li>
              <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
              <li ><a style="color:black" href="../../cikis.aspx">Çıkış Yap</a></li>

          </ul>
        </li>
```

Comment: Are you receiving errors in your browser console? I believe the problem is not in bootstrap, if it works once, it should work wherever it is. Maybe default.aspx is loading correct references to bootstrap scripts and css, and other pages won't load them.

Comment: see http://getbootstrap.com/components/#dropdowns for reference

Comment: haha you are right. I didn't think it. checked it now and  solved. thanks my friend @theCodeSurgeon